# Model in another path

Tags: yii2

When trying to use the USER model, the following error message:

```
Class 'app\models\User' not found
```

my USER model is located at: **amnah\yii2\user\models\User**

If so, how should I do? Specifying the location of the model?

**UPDATE**

My VIEW.PHP file is so:

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;
use amnah\yii2\user\models\User;
```

But don't work :(

**SOLVED**

I change my function and specified the desired model:

```
public function getUser()
{
    $user = Yii::$app->getModule("user")->model("User");
    return $this->hasOne($user::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the namespace of your class?

You don't need to worry about the real file path, but be sure that the namepace in the your User model is the same that you trying to use.

Example:

some\path\User.php

```
<?php
namespace my\path;

class User { ..
```

To use this file you need to use the same namespace of the file:

```
<?php
use my\path\User
...
```

Comment: the namespace is: namespace amnah\yii2\user\models;

But still trying to find the USER in: 'app\models\User'

Comment: the error show on line 80 on my model SOLICITATION:

`return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);`

Comment: its works :)

i change my **public function getUser()**

Answer (score 0):

If amnah is a vendor try

```
vendor\amnah\yii2\user\models\User
```

Comment: don't work... where i use this?
My VIEW.PHP file is so: 

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;
use amnah\yii2\user\models\User;